# OpengGL makefile linker error in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, undefined-reference, glew

I been trying to make Makefile for medium sized project but it is no go for me:

```
DPS=-Wall -lglfw -lGLEW
main: glfw.o shader.o
    g++ $(DPS) glfw.o shader.o -o main.run

glfw.o: glfw.cpp
    g++ $(DPS) -c glfw.cpp

shader.o: shader.cpp shader.h
    g++ $(DPS) -c shader.cpp

clear:
    rm *.o main.run
```

When i run make it throws up:

```
g++ -Wall -lglfw -lGLEW -c glfw.cpp
glfw.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
glfw.cpp:48:17: warning: unused variable ‘EBO’ [-Wunused-variable]
  GLuint VBO,VAO,EBO;
                 ^
g++ -Wall -lglfw -lGLEW -c shader.cpp
g++ -Wall -lglfw -lGLEW glfw.o shader.o -o main.run
glfw.o: In function `main':
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `glfwGetVersionString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `glewGetString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `glGetString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `glGetString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `glGetString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `glGetString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `glewInit'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `glewGetErrorString'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x34f): undefined reference to `__glewGenVertexArrays'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x372): undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x38a): undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x3ca): undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x402): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x420): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x42a): undefined reference to `glClear'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x436): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
glfw.cpp:(.text+0x442): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
shader.o: In function `BasicShader::BasicShader(char const*, char const*)':
shader.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderiv'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x360): undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x371): undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgram'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x3a1): undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `__glewLinkProgram'
shader.o: In function `BasicShader::use()':
shader.cpp:(.text+0x533): undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
shader.o: In function `BasicShader::setBool(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const':
shader.cpp:(.text+0x55d): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x583): undefined reference to `__glewUniform1i'
shader.o: In function `BasicShader::setInt(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int) const':
shader.cpp:(.text+0x5b3): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x5d9): undefined reference to `__glewUniform1i'
shader.o: In function `BasicShader::setFloat(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, float) const':
shader.cpp:(.text+0x60b): undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
shader.cpp:(.text+0x631): undefined reference to `__glewUniform1f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

This is main file:

```
#include "shader.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//int main( int argc, char** argv)
int main()
{

    if( !glfwInit() )
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "<++>", NULL, NULL );
    if( !window )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error on window creating" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    std::cout << "GLFW version                : " << glfwGetVersionString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLEW_VERSION                : " << glewGetString( GLEW_VERSION ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VERSION                  : " << glGetString( GL_VERSION ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VENDOR                   : " << glGetString( GL_VENDOR ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_RENDERER                 : " << glGetString( GL_RENDERER ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION : " << glGetString( GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION ) << std::endl;

    glewExperimental = true;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if( err!= GLEW_OK )
    {
        std::cerr << "Glew init failed!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString( err ) << std::endl;
    }

    GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.75,-0.75,0,0,0,
        -0.75,0.75,0,0,1,
        0.75,0.75,0,1,1,
        0.75,-0.75,0,1,0
    };


    GLuint VBO,VAO,EBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(GLfloat)*5,(void*)0);




    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )
    {
        glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );



        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Shader.h:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>



class BasicShader
{
    public:
    unsigned int ID;
    BasicShader(const char* vShader,const char* fShader);

    void use();

    void setBool(const std::string &name,bool value) const;
    void setInt(const std::string &name,int value) const;
    void setFloat(const std::string &name,float value) const;
};

#endif
```

Shader.cpp:

```
#include "shader.h"

BasicShader::BasicShader(const char* vShader,const char* fShader)
{
    std::fstream vPath(vShader, std::ios::in);
    std::ostringstream vStream;

    if (vPath.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "BASICSHADER::VERTEX::FAILED_TO_OPEN" << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int vShaderID = 0;
    vShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    std::string vShaderString = "";
    vStream << vPath.rdbuf();

    vShaderString = vStream.str();

    const char* vShaderSource = vShaderString.c_str();

    glShaderSource(vShaderID,1,&vShaderSource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShaderID);

    #ifndef DEBUG_MODE
    int success;
    char infoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderiv(vShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "BASICSHADER::VERTEX::FAILED_TO_COMPILE\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    #endif

    unsigned int fShaderID = 0;
    std::fstream fPath(fShader,std::ios::in);

    if (fPath.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "BASICSHADER::FRAGMENT::FAILED_TO_OPEN" << std::endl;
    } 

    std::string fShaderString = "";
    std::stringstream fSteam;
    fSteam << fPath.rdbuf();
    fShaderString = fSteam.str();


    const char* fShaderSource = fShaderString.c_str();

    fShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fShaderID,1,&fShaderSource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShaderID);

    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    glGetShaderiv(vShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        std::cout << "BASICSHADER::FRAGMENT::FAILED_TO_COMPILE\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    #endif

    ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ID,vShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ID,fShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "BASICSHADER::PROGRAM::ID::FAILED_TO_LINK\n" << infoLog << std::endl;

    }
    #endif
}

    void BasicShader::use()
{
    glUseProgram(ID);
}

    void BasicShader::setBool(const std::string &name,bool value) const
{
    int uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ID,name.c_str());
    glUniform1i(uniformLoc,static_cast<int>(value));
}

    void BasicShader::setInt(const std::string &name,int value) const
{
    int uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ID,name.c_str());
    glUniform1i(uniformLoc,value);
}


    void BasicShader::setFloat(const std::string &name,float value) const
{
    int uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ID,name.c_str());
    glUniform1f(uniformLoc,value);
}
```

Comment: your library argument order is just screwed

Comment: Makefile should be formated as g++ -c source.cpp -llibary_name and for linking g++ source1.o source2.o -o run -llibary_name. The order of libary argument is -Wall -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL. This is what it got working.